# How to use case statement when both conditions are true and you need to display only one as a result

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, case

query:

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT userId,
  sessionId,
  CASE
    WHEN b.pageType = 'confirm' THEN 'User_converted'
  ELSE
  'Not_converted'
END
  AS conversion_index

  
FROM (
  SELECT
    userId,
    sessionId,
    p.createdat page_time,
    p.pageType
  FROM
    ccart.sessv6_79633508 AS sess,
    UNNEST(pages)p
  WHERE
    sess.createdAt >= TIMESTAMP('2021-07-01')
    AND sess.createdAt <= TIMESTAMP ('2021-10-11')
    AND userId = '206885636.2915067519'
    AND sessionId = 'GH178U' )b
```

I have tried this query and I want result as yes or No for field conversion_index

but as both statements are true for a given user, hence two rows are appearing

All I want is if page type = 'confirm' condition is true, then return value as 'yes' else No

Comment: BigQuery or PostgreSQL? Please do not tag databases not involved. Also it's a CASE _expression_ not a statement.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag one database only.

Comment: `select userid, sessionid, max(case when b.pageType = 'Confirm' Then 'Yes' else 'No' End) as conversion_index group by userid, sessionid`

Comment: Please show schema for the tables involved, and remove SQL irrelevant to the problem, such as timestamp ranges in the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

If user has seen page type = 'confirm' even once, then value should be 'Yes', otherwise 'No':

```
SELECT
      userId
    , sessionId
    , max(conversion_index) AS conversion_index
FROM (
    SELECT userId
        , sessionId
        , CASE 
            WHEN p.pageType = 'confirm'
                THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
            END AS conversion_index
    FROM ccart.sessv6_79633508 AS sess
        , UNNEST(pages) p
    WHERE sess.createdAt >= TIMESTAMP ('2021-07-01')
        AND sess.createdAt <= TIMESTAMP ('2021-10-11')
        AND userId = '206885636.2915067519'
        AND sessionId = 'GH178U'
    ) b
GROUP BY
      userId
    , sessionId
```

If you wanted up to 2 rows for each user (one for Yes the other for No) try moving the original case expression down one "layer" of the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      userId
    , sessionId
    , conversion_index
FROM (
    SELECT userId
        , sessionId
        , CASE 
            WHEN p.pageType = 'confirm'
                THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
            END AS conversion_index
    FROM ccart.sessv6_79633508 AS sess
        , UNNEST(pages) p
    WHERE sess.createdAt >= TIMESTAMP ('2021-07-01')
        AND sess.createdAt <= TIMESTAMP ('2021-10-11')
        AND userId = '206885636.2915067519'
        AND sessionId = 'GH178U'
    ) b
```

So if **all** for a user pages are `p.pageType = 'confirm'` you would get **Yes** only, if **all** for a user pages are **not** `p.pageType = 'confirm'` you would get **No** only, otherwise you get one row Yes and another row No for that user.

Comment: Paul, thank you for your suggestion but what I want to convey is that if user has seen page type = 'confirm' even once, then value should be 'Yes' . No need to look any other statement                 Only when page type is not = 'confirm' then value should be 'No'

Comment: Facts of of this nature really belong in the question. However I have added to my answer (ironically this was my original guess as to your intent, but changed my mind).

Comment: Paul, for the scenario that I presented   , If user page type will be 'confirm'  then, max (conversion_index) will display value as single row 'Yes' only   but if page type will not be confirm in  that session, then value will appear as 'No' only,  am I right ?

Comment: MAX(of 'Yes' or ' No')  = 'Yes'. So if there is just 1 value of 'Yes' then you get 'Yes' as final result. Otherwise all values will be 'No' and the maximum of all 'No's = 'No'